# Showing that a decreasing sequence $A_1 \supset A_2 \supset \dots$ of events with a limit $A = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty$ has a probability limit

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $A_1 \supset A_2 \dots$ be decreasing sequence of events with a limit $A = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$. It is known that an increasing sequence of events with a limiting event has a probability limit, that is $B_1 \subset B_2 \dots, B = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \in \mathcal{F} \implies \mathbb{P}[B_n] \uparrow \mathbb{P}[B], n \to \infty$. We want to show that $\mathbb{P}[A_n] \downarrow \mathbb{P}[A]$ exists.

Since $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, it is closed under complements, arbitrary unions and intersections. Thus if $A = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n \in \mathcal{F}$, then also $A^C = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n^C \in \mathcal{F}$. Since for any event $E$ it true that $\mathbb{P}[E^C] = 1 - \mathbb{P}[E]$, we have that

$A_n^C \uparrow A^C \Longleftrightarrow \mathbb{P}[A_n^C] \uparrow \mathbb{P}[A^C] = 1 - \mathbb{P}[A]$. Since also the partial union $\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k$ is an event, the complement rule applies also for it and thus $1 - \mathbb{P}[A_n] = \mathbb{P}[A_n^C] \uparrow \mathbb{P}[A^C] = 1 - \mathbb{P}[A]\Longleftrightarrow -\mathbb{P}[A_n] \uparrow -\mathbb{P}[A] \Longleftrightarrow \mathbb{P}[A_n] \downarrow \mathbb{P}[A]$ as $n \to \infty$, as $-\mathbb{P}[A_n]$ was an increasing sequence.

How does my proof hold?

Comment: looks fine to me.

Comment: **countable unions/intersections**, not arbitrary ones. So $A \in \mathcal F$ if all $A_n$ are.